# Repeated column mapping in many to one relationship (Spring JPA)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I run my springboot project, I get error:

```
Column 'transactionNumber' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.myproject.Entities.IndividualItemsTransactionEntity' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)
```

My current project has 2 tables. One is of the transaction table (There is only one of these per transaction)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TransactionsEntity {

    @Id
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "transactionNumber", columnDefinition = "varchar(12)", length = 12, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String transactionNumber;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "transactionNumber", nullable = false)
        List<IndividualItemsTransactionEntity> individualItemsTransactionEntities;

//more redacted stuff
    }
```

Each transaction then has many IndividualItemsTransactionEntity for each item purchased in the transaction

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "individual_items_transaction")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class IndividualItemsTransactionEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "individualItemTransactionID", columnDefinition = "bigint", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long individualItemTransactionID;

    //We are using hibernate nullable = false to allow transaction entity ID to generate first before populating
    //all transaction item entities with non nullable
    @Column(name = "transactionNumber", columnDefinition = "varchar(12)", length = 12, nullable = false)
    private String transactionNumber; // <- this basically is referring back to the other transaction table

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "transactionNumber", nullable = false)
    TransactionsEntity transactionsEntity;
}
```

I basically want the SQL equivalent of:

```
FROM transactions JOIN individual_items_transaction ON transactions.transactionNumber = individual_items_transaction.transactionNumber
```

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

The entities should look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "individual_items_transaction")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class IndividualItemsTransactionEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "individualItemTransactionID", columnDefinition = "bigint", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long individualItemTransactionID

    //We are using hibernate nullable = false to allow transaction entity ID to generate first before populating
    //all transaction item entities with non nullable
    @Column(name = "transactionNumber", columnDefinition = "varchar(12)", length = 12, nullable = 

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "transactionNumber", nullable = false)
    TransactionsEntity transactionsEntity;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TransactionsEntity {

    @Id
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "transactionNumber", columnDefinition = "varchar(12)", length = 12, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private String transactionNumber;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @mappedBy(“transactionEntity”)
        List<IndividualItemsTransactionEntity> individualItemsTransactionEntities;

//more redacted stuff
    }
```